# Horizontal Row View : A RenderFlex overflowed by 66 pixels on the right

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I put ListView to show tabs scrolling horizontally, but the problem is that they are displayed in the middle of screen and I want it to be shown at the top of screen.

Is there any way to solve this and show this list at top of screen?

Here is how I did it:

```
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return  Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:20,top: 10, ),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text(
                      'All',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey
                      ),),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:20,top: 10, ),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text(
                      'Cars',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey
                      ),),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:20,top: 10, ),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text(
                      'Buildings',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey
                      ),),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0, right:20,top: 10, ),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text(
                      'Assorted Devices',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey
                      ),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Remove `Row` from your `ListView`, and make its children direct `children` of the `ListView`

Comment: I did it but nothing is displayed now.. Or What should I type after return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Container`, `ListView.builder` and `Row`, simply use:

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    _buildInkWell('All'),
    _buildInkWell('Cars'),
    _buildInkWell('Building'),
    _buildInkWell('Assorted Devices'),
  ],
)

Widget _buildInkWell(String text) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 20.0,
      right: 20,
      top: 10,
    ),
    child: InkWell(
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `crossAxisAlignment` in Row, it will start your UI from Top

```
         Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            //...
             )
```